# Assigning IP addresses and subnetting on a home network

Tags: router, ethernet, dhcp, wireless-access-point, subnet

After 4 days of trying, googling, and tearing my hair, I have managed to bring down the internet at my home. I needed to implement the network as follows, however my efforts have managed to bring down the little that was working from before:

[image: Please see the [NETWORK DIAGRAM][1]]

```
Green Boxes - Front and Back yards, Outside
Orange, Yellow and Purple Box - Different rooms, Inside
```

1. I need all computers, tablets etc. to have a DHCP IP on the 192.168.1.xxx subnet.
2. The Modem/Router has a static ip 192.168.0.1
3. The Purple AP connected to the Modem/Router has a internal static ip WAN - 192.168.0.2 and LAN - 192.168.1.1 It has DHCP Server for IP range 192.168.1.100-200 All other AP have DHCP off.
4. One of the green AP and the purple AP are WiFi routers, repurposed as APs. The rest APs are dedicated APs.
5. While I reset and setup dedicated APs, they have a IP but they become invisible in network scans after being configured with connections. I don't know if this is supposed to happen? The switches are all unmanaged, and as normal don't have IP.
6. The wifi routers repurposed as APs, use IP addresses during setup and regular operation. Here I am unable to set up their WAN and LAN IP on 192.168.1.XXX which is what I need to have the connecting devices on the same subnet.
7. How can I get all the APs to be on the same subnet? Can I have the dedicated APs accessible on individual IP address during regular operation? How could I better implement a network with these devices which is better/more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

1. After reading 3, this shouldn't be an issue.
2. Shouldn't matter for the rest of your network.
3. You may need to have the WAN use DHCP depending on how your modem receives its IP address from your ISP.  If your modem simply acts as a bridge, then your router will need to have your public IP address.
4. Shouldn't matter if it's an actual WiFi router or just an AP.
5. That depends on the way the devices were designed.  Without knowing what kind of APs they are, or their model numbers, we can only guess.
6. For your routers, simply disable their DHCP, give them static LAN IP addresses and plug the cables into the LAN ports.  There's no need for you to use the WAN ports as WAN ports are designed to limit/block incoming traffic.  The LAN ports on the other hand will act as a switch between the LAN ports and WiFi.
7. Read above for the first part of this bullet point.  Without knowing more about your house, the wiring situation, and what you're attempting to do, we can only guess at how to better implement your network, for the most part though, it seems serviceable.